# xcode .sh permission denied

Tags: xcode

I received a program from my colleague, but my mac can not run it as the picture. My two friends can run it, so the code is ok. I have deleted and download xcode again. Also I have tried "sudo chmod +x xxx/xxx.sh" but it does not work it.

[image: picture]

Comment: oh  I dealt with it .just use "sudo chmod +x xxx/xxx.sh" several times until "xx.sh permission denied" disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove your CocoaPods and run `pod setup` again.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue.

it's resolved using following terminal command

```
chmod a+x "path of permission denied"
```